# Customize messages format using winston.js and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I'm using winston.js in my nodejs project, what I'm looking for is, to output two different custom messages into different type of transport (console,file).
console mode:

```
return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}
```

file mode (in the file I want to display only the message and level) :

```
return ` ${level} : ${message}
```

Here's my code :

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = format;
const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {

 return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}`;
  }
 });

const logger = createLogger({
 format: combine(
  label({ label: 'hello  |' }),
  timestamp(),
  myFormat
),
transports: [new transports.Console(),
  new transports.File({
   filename: api.log,
   level: 'info'
  })
]
 });
 logger.stream = {
   write: function(message, encoding) {

   logger.info(message);
 },
  };
 module.exports = logger;
```

With this code I have the same output, any help please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the code above but I got the same message in the console and output file

Comment: OK that's obvious but have you tried figuring out how winstone.js logger works? or you just need someone to give straight-up code so you can copy paste?!

Comment: the problem is, to display two different logs,one to the console the second in the file, i checked the doc I didnt find any thing interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Winston.js ver3 on **Transport accepts Format**

In order to have different log format for different outputs you need to create different Format objects and pass them to your Transport constructors.

So in your case:

- You've created myFormat for `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}` instead of passing it to `createLogger` you need to pass it to `Console` constructor.
- You need to create another `Format` for `${level} : ${message}`
- Pass that `Format` to `format` property of `File` transport constructor

You can see example with passing different format to Console in  winston.js project source: 
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/examples/quick-start.js

Comment: thanks for your answer Milan, but what do you mean by console and file constructor, could u give an exemple please ?

Comment: like this :new transports.Console(myFormat), ?

Comment: thnak you very much Milan for your help :) its work now